# How to combine two ffmpeg commands - adding blur bar and adding logo and subtitle?

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg

I run the following two ffmpeg command lines to create videos with blur bar, logo and subtitle.

1. Adding blur bars

   ```
   ffmpeg -i input.mkv -lavfi "[0:v]scale=iw:iw*3/4,boxblur=luma_radius=min(h\,w)/40:luma_power=3:chroma_radius=min(cw\,ch)/40:chroma_power=1[bg];[bg][0:v]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2,setsar=1,crop=h=iw*3/4" blur_bar_added.mkv
   ```
2. Adding logo and subtitle

   ```
   ffmpeg -i blur_bar_added.mkv -i logo.png -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref=iw*0.15:ow/mdar[wm][v];[v][wm]overlay=W-w-5:5,ass=input.ass" output.mkv
   ```

I would like to know how to combine them to run once. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -i logo.png -lavfi "[0:v]scale=iw:iw*3/4,boxblur=luma_radius=min(h\,w)/40:luma_power=3:chroma_radius=min(cw\,ch)/40:chroma_power=1[bg];[bg][0:v]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2,setsar=1,crop=h=iw*3/4[v];[1][v]scale2ref=iw*0.15:ow/mdar[wm][v];[v][wm]overlay=W-w-5:5,ass=input.ass" output.mkv`

The filters for logo scale2ref and overlay go after the main video is composed.

Comment: It returns the following error.

[AVFilterGraph @ 0x55c9126b9b40] Bad (empty?) label found in the following: "[]scale2ref=iw*0.15:ow/mdar[wm][v];[v][wm]overlay=W-w-5:5,ass=in.ass".
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument

Comment: Corrected label